# What items in the Google API credentials must remain private?

Tags: google-api, google-oauth

I've seen a few posts stating that you need to keep this private, but my questions is which items in specific are sensitive.

My understanding is that just the `private_key` needs to remain private, but i wasn't sure if the `private_key_id`, `client_id`, or `client_email` give any sensitive information away.

In other words, if this entire object were made public (for example posted on github) with the exception of the `private_key`, is that okay?

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "",
  "private_key_id": "",
  "private_key": "",
  "client_email": "",
  "client_id": "",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "",
  "universe_domain": "googleapis.com"
}
```